# Old JavaScript Function Crashes Browser

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm integrating a mootools script onto a page which has very old JavaScript functions which run a navigation vertical menu. This old script will be hard to change now.

The line breaking is:

```
function stgobj(id) {
    with(document) return nIE && nVER < 5 ? all[id] : nNN4 ? layers[id] : getElementById(id);
}
```

Not sure exactly what's it's purpose, but it looks like it's rendering some elements. If commented the menu will disappear.

FF, Chrome, IE(doesn't crash, but menu does not render)

Any quick patch to resolve the browsers crashing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like its purpose is to return the element corresponding to the given ID. The code simply uses some different methods based on the browser - `document.all` for IE5 and earlier, and `document.layers` for Netscape 4. Unless you need to support those ancient browsers, you could alter the function to return just `document.getElementById(id)`. Or better yet, ditch this function altogether and call `document.getElementById` directly.

However, if it's crashing modern browsers like Firefox and Chrome, then you should also look at the browser detection logic (the code that populates the `nIE`, `nVER` and `nNN4` variables), otherwise it might just end up crashing elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It's a "compatibility" function for `document.getElementById`. I think you should be able to equal it:

```
stgobj = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```